# What to do when you only have a partial answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Many times I find myself with relevant, sourced information when I look at a question, but won't have a complete answer. For example, in [this recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44800/5323), the question asked for when large-scale slaughterhouses became common practice, and rabbinical positions for and against them. I know exactly one thing about that, which is the source I linked to in [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44819/5323) explaining how certain practices of large-scale slaughter worked halachically (based on a comparison to Erev Yom Kipuur). This is not a complete answer by itself, but it's certainly relevant to the question.*
I'm not the only one with this issue: see, for example, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44929/can-one-use-a-gas-grill-for-both-meat-and-dairy-with-lots-of-other-caveats#comment118318_44929) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36083/5323).

So my Meta question is -- in a situation like that, is it better to:

1. Post an answer with just the information I have.
2. Post an answer with the disclaimer that it is incomplete. (which is what I have been doing)
3. Post a comment with the information that I have.
4. Something else?

   ---

   *<sub>Other answers where I have done this include but may not be limited to [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43723/5323) [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44890/5323) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40168/5323).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, whether the asker delineated parts to his question (1. Why is this done? 2. How long has it been done? ― Answer: So-and-so says it's done because of such-and-such.) or not (What's the custom? ― Answer: The Ashkenazic custom is such-and-such.) it's fine as an answer and needn't be a comment. And it should be worded so readers aren't confused: so they know it's a partial answer.